# wrong format when saving to file

Tags: c#

I am trying to save a String Builder to a file but it doesn't make new line.
the output should look like
[image]

output without new line
[image]

```
class Program
{
    static public void justify(List<string> words, int width)
    {
        //some code to build the arrays
        int ii = 0, jj;
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        do
        {
            jj = result[ii];

            for(int k = ii; k < jj; k++)
            {
                builder.Append(words[k] + " ");
            }

            builder.Append("\n");
            ii = jj;
        }
        while(jj < words.Count);
        Console.WriteLine(builder.ToString());
        StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter("output.txt");
        file.Write(builder.ToString());
        file.Close();
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string file_extention, file1;
        file1 = Console.ReadLine();
        file_extention = "C:\\Users\\sayed\\Desktop\\" + file1 + ".txt";
        string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@file_extention);
        result = text.Split(' ').ToList();
        justify(result, 10);
    }
}
```

Comment: Notepad expects line endings to be "\r\n". You can either append that, or just use `StringBuilder.AppendLine`. The `\n` chars you're adding are there, but Notepad does not show them. You can open the same file with Notepad++ and you will see the line breaks.

Comment: Yeah, just use `AppendLine()`

Comment: If you're working on a windows machine, you may need to add a carriage return character before new line: `builder.Append("\r\n");`

Comment: problem solved I used "\r\n"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because the you should use `\r\n` for new lines in Windows. `\n` is Unix. You should use

```
builder.AppendLine();
```

which does this automatically. More precisely, `AppendLine()` appends a `\r\n` on non-Unix platforms and a string `\n` on Unix platforms.

Note that your file does indeed contain the `\n` which some editors do interpret as line breaks even on Windows. Notepad, for instance, does not.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
builder.Append("\n");
```

with

```
builder.Append(Environment.NewLine);
```

Then open your file with notepad++ instead of window's default text editor.

I believe your \n characters are being ignored by notepad and so they aren't rendering. On Windows machines, it expects a \r\n to render a newline and Environment.NewLine will make sure you get the right one.

Comment: Why roll your own for this?  `builder.AppendLine()` exists and should be used to _append a new line_

Comment: builder.AppendLine() is perfectly acceptable... Environment.NewLine is still useful to know about in case he wasn't using a string builder.

Comment: 100% agree with bringing up `Environment.NewLine`. Probably not *"the best"* solution, but knowing it exists can solve plenty of other problems OP could encounter (in this program and elsewhere).

Comment: @ZakkDiaz Fair enough, just seemed like for _this specific question_ `AppendLine()` is the obvious choice, [it uses Environment.NewLine internally](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/text/stringbuilder.cs,748).  Probably good to mention both!